# Istio routing to chaos testing

Tags: java, istio, istio-sidecar

I'm reading [traffic management documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/) and also use Istio for [chaos testing](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/04/10/istio-chaos-engineering#never_gonna_give_you_up).

I know we can use some headers value to routing traffic for AB testing, but what I would like to know is if I can do the same to return an error in one service or make a delay, as the Istio chaos testing provides.

So I can end up making request with header `request-type:chaos`, and for those we will apply the chaos testing YAML config, but not for the rest of request.

Comment: Which Istio and Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: networking.istio.io/v1beta1

Comment: Please check my answer with the newest edit.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems is not working for gRPC communication

Comment: Please provide logs from Istio ingress gateway (get pod name with command `kubectl get pods -n istio-system` and then `kubectl logs istio-ingressgateway-{some-random-strings} -n istio-system`). Please provide more information about your setup (Istio and Kubernetes versions, the deployment / vitrual services / gateways etc config file) and [make your issue reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The `RouteRule` (used in the second link you sent) is [deprecated and replaced by `VirtualService`](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2018/v1alpha3-routing/):

> `VirtualService`, `DestinationRule`, and `ServiceEntry` replace `RouteRule`, `DestinationPolicy`, and `EgressRule` respectively.

Good instructions on how to configure an HTTP delay fault is presented in this -> [Fault Injection](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/fault-injection/) documentation.

Example YAML config for your header (`request-type:chaos`) based on [Ingress Gateways](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/) and [Fault Injection](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/fault-injection/) documentations:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
 name: httpbin
spec:
 hosts:
 - "httpbin.example.com"
 gateways:
 - httpbin-gateway
 http:
 - fault:
     delay:
       fixedDelay: 7s
       percent: 100
   match:
   - headers:
       request-type:
         exact: chaos
   route:
   - destination:
       port:
         number: 80
       host: my-echo-service
 - route:
   - destination:
       port:
         number: 80
       host: my-nginx-service
```

**EDIT:** Should work as well for `apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1`.